# Nightwatch.js chromedriver instances stay in memory

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, bdd, nightwatch.js

When i use this simple test script, `chromedriver.exe` stays in memory.

**simple-test.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  'Test url': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
      .expect.element('input[name=q]').to.be.visible

    browser.end()
  }
};
```

**Nightwatch.js configuration file**

```js
const chromedriverPath = require('chromedriver').path;
const geckodriverPath = require('geckodriver').path;
const seleniumServerPath = require('selenium-server').path;
const now = Date.now()

module.exports = {
  output_folder: 'tests/reports',
  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    log_path: 'tests',
    server_path: seleniumServerPath,
    cli_args: {
      'selenium.LOGGER.level': 'FINEST',
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriverPath,
      'webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging': 'true',
      'webdriver.chrome.logfile': 'tests\\chromedriver-' + now + '.log',
      'webdriver.gecko.driver': geckodriverPath,
    },
  },
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      globals: {
        url: 'http://localhost:1337'
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
      },
    },
    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The output shows no errors, but `chromedriver.exe` never terminates itself, i've to kill it. Am i doing something wrong ?

Note: i'am using Nightwatch.js v0.9.21 and chromedriver v2.41.578737 on Window 10 Pro 64 bits

Note 2: The equivalent script in *selenium* does not exhibit this behavior, chromedriver shut itself down after `browser.quit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by migrating my project to nightwatch 1.0.6 (beta) (+ nightwatch-api 0.4.0)